# manage comma seperated-fields

Tags: centos, text-processing, regular-expression, csv

I do have a big data inside text file as the following format:

```
x, xx, xxx, xxxx, , , ,
x, xx, , xxxx, xxxx,
```

so i would like to delete from file all lines which field number 3 after comma is empty

so the result gonna be

```
x, xx, xxx, xxxx, , , ,
```

so how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -F' *, *' '$3' file
x, xx, xxx, xxxx, , , ,
```

With `-F` we set the field separator to the regular expression `␣*,␣*` (space, star, comma, space, star).  This expression matches any comma surrounded by zero or more spaces.

The actual `awk` script is just `$3`, which means that if the third field is non-empty, the line will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '$3!~/^[[:space:]]*$/' file
```

The output:

```
x, xx, xxx, xxxx, , , ,
```

---

- `-F,` - field separator
- `$3!~/^[[:space:]]*$/` - considering only those lines having *non-empty* 3rd field (doesn't consist of whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if /^([^,]*,){2}\h*[^\h,]/' yourcsvfile
```

We look past the first two csv fields then check whether the end of the 2nd and beginning of 3rd fields has at least non-horizontal-space, non-comma. When it matches we've found our line.

```
perl -F, -lane 'print if $F[2] =~ /\S/' yourcsvfile
```

We split the line into comma-delimited fields, stored in array `@F`, then look for the 3rd `$F[2]` and see whether that has at least one non-whitespace `\S` in it.

#### Sed

```
sed -e '
   s/,/\n/2;s/,/\n/2
   /\n[[:space:]]*\n/d
   y/\n/,/
' yourfile.csv
```

Mark out the 3rd field by newlines. Then when if there's all whitespace or nothing in between the two markers => line to be deleted. OTW, we revert the markers and `sed` prints the pattern space by default.